Ads test beginning December 3, 2024
We’ve been exploring the concept of using open auction to manage advertising on some Stack Exchange sites. Under this model, advertisers (who have been organized into categories based on their products) “bid” for an advertising spot. There is a floor price - a minimum price for the spot, and all bids must exceed that floor price.  This community will be testing the open auction experiment, beginning on December 3, 2024.  For more information or to provide feedback on the experiment, please refer to the post on Meta Stack Exchange.

I am trying to understand how this works. Does this mean the amount and positioning of ads will not change and they will just become more targeted? Or is there an intention to increase amount of ads? How does this play along with the current model of decreasing amount of ads for mebers with 200 rep?

Honestly?  I filter all the adverts on as many sites as possible.  My guess is I won't even see them.
The average non-technical user, on the other hand, might get turned off.  Lets see what the usage stats say after a month.
